# Data is ambiguous for type lookup in this context?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am converting my project to latest swift 3. But I am stuck at one position.

```
 func nsdataToJSON(data: Data) -> AnyObject? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Gives me error on `func nsdataToJSON(data: Data) -> AnyObject? {` Data is ambiguous for type lookup in this context.

How can i use in swift 3?

Comment: Let change to `func nsdataToJSON(data: Data) -> Any? {}`. It's okay for me!

Comment: You need to use Any instead of AnyObject in Swift 3. So replace AnyObject? to Any?.

Answer (score 1):

While using your function in Playground i get the error

> 'jsonObject' produces 'Any', not the expected contextual result type
>   'AnyObject?'

so after changing `AnyObject` to `Any`, it is working

```
func nsdataToJSON(data: Data) -> Any? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil
}
```